# How can I port an Apache RewriteCond and RewriteRule to ngnix?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have to convert an Apache reverse-proxy configuration that uses RewriteCond and RewriteRule,  to Nginx.

How can I convert something like this to nginx configuration?

(this is in the main/only `<VirtualHost *:443>` block)

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stagingapi$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://staging-zone.mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RewriteRule has as first parameter regular expression which is matching all URI starting with `/` and as second parameter a substitution, which redirects "stagingapi" site (R flag) to https://staging-zone.mydomain.com/

Try with something like:

```
server{
  listen 443;
  server_name stagingapi;
  return 301 $scheme://staging-zone.mydomain.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

You can replace `$scheme` with `https` if you want to redirect all the time to HTTPS to have the same behavior as in apache.

Comment: Thanks Mircea that helped alot.

Comment: You are welcome!